# Forum Comment Section with PhP

Tags: php, database, forms, quotes, forum

I'm a just a novice programmer, and i'm making a forum to improve my skills but i'm walking against a problem right now. 
This is the Problem with the code:

The problem is: we can't use Single Quotes and we want to use them and dubble quotes.

This is where it goes into the Database:

```
// get data that sent from form 
$topic=$_POST['topic'];
$detail=$_POST['detail'];
$name=$_SESSION['display'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

and this is a part of the form:

```
<tr>
    <td width="14%"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
    <td width="2%">:</td>
    <td width="84%"><input name="topic" type="text" id="topic" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><strong>Detail</strong></td>
    <td valign="top">:</td>
    <td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="3" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

What do i have to add so we can Use single and dubble quotes? What do i have to do? because if some one uses a Single Quote the Message crashes..

This is the Error message that i give

```
if($result){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href=index.php>View your topic</a>";
header("Location: localhost/forum/");
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

And this is where it goes in:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $qtbl_name(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql)
```

;

Comment: I am guessing you're using mysql_ functions, so [escape your variables](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), an even better solution would be to take notice of the big red box on that page, and do what it suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You're running in a thing called "sql injections" and this is a serious problem you should care about.

Please read http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string and use this function to escape special characters of your input data.

It seems, that you have a query like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (`topic`) VALUES ('$topic');"
```

So your generated query-string is maybe like

```
$topic = "foobar";
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (`topic`) VALUES ('$topic');"
echo $query;
```

will result in:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`topic`) VALUES ('foobar');
```

which is nice. but:

```
$topic = "f'); delete from tbl;";
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (`topic`) VALUES ('$topic');"
echo $query;
```

will return:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`topic`) VALUES('f'); delete from tbl;
```

and this is not what you wish going to happen.

To reach the next level of your programming skills in PHP you should read the PDO-documentation (http://php.net/pdo) and learn more about the use of parameters in a sql statement :)

Comment: Soo i've to make a variable of the thing that get's imported? i've also changed the code above, so you can see how it goes in

Comment: I have nothing to add to my answer; please follow my links. Your code is as expected. Use mysql_real_escape_string or - better - read about PDO.
Please accept my answer if you're happy.